# Datatable.getchanges - Which column changed

Tags: vb.net, datatable, bindingsource

I have a form in detail view with a binding navigator.  When i click next, if there is a change, i get asked if I want to save it.  So if I know I didnt change anything and the rowstate is still coming up modified, how can i determine what was modified.

I get the row that was modified with dim changetable as datatable = table.getchanges(datarowstate.modified).  I am getting 1 row as i suspect, it is the correct row bc it is the same as the current row i am on.  So, how can I determine what exactly changed in that row.  I can't seem to find what changed.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can subscribe to events for the DataTable, ColumnChanged should do the trick. See my MSDN basic code sample.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Working-with-DataTable-2ff5f158?redir=0

Comment: I am trying to implement your code in a way.  I tried setting bsdata to my bindingsource but then i get that datatable is not a member of 'DataTable' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource'.

Comment: In regards to DataTable is not a member of BindingSource, there is a language extension method in the download under the folder CodeModules in LanguageExtensions.vb, include it and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this where the 1 is the column index. I just used a string, .ToString to test. Your column could be any type.

```
Dim row As DataRow = MyTable.Rows(0)
Dim x As String = (row(1, DataRowVersion.Original)).ToString
Debug.Print(x)
```

Comment: If i do DataRowVersion.Modified as well, will that show both and then i just need to find the column that has a difference?

Comment: Perhaps a loop. Instead of hardcoding the 1, use a variable index. For index = 0 to MyTable.Columns.Count -1. then it would be If row(index, DataRowVersion.Current) Is row(index, DataRowVersion.Proposed) Then

Comment: I don't think .Modified is part of the enumeration.